# Como modificar el LinearLayout de un fragment

Tags: java, android-studio

Necesito un ejemplo de como modificar un LinearLayout de un fragment(Por ejemplo cambiar el color). Se que el metodo setBackgroundColor(Color.X) funciona pero desde actividades. He probado ttambien con .setView().setBackgroundColor(Color.X) pero se me digue cerrando la app. Dejo un fragmento del código de ejemplo:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
        LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ln_alumnos);

        //ln.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); se cierra la app

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alumnos, container, false);

    }
```

Comment: Que tal si agrega el setBackground() dentro del bloque try catch y un toast dentro de la parte catch, y nos dices que excepción lanzó 
      \n 
   try{ln.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);}catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(nombreDeMainActivity.this,""+e,9).show();}//Y nos dices que excepción te dió

Comment: y si le añade el color en vez de por codigo por propiedades en el xml de diseño

Comment: Hay veces que se nesecita añadirlo en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: @DanielBriceño Perdona no redacte bien el comentario en el código, no lanza ningun error simplemente se cierra la app. Quiero recordar por si no queda  claro que estoy intentando modificar el elemento desde un fragment. El ln.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); funciona si estuviera en una activity pero desde un fragment este método no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADO.

Mi error fue que estaba inflando la vista y añadiendola a la variable v dentro del método:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Lo que he hecho es usar mi vista inflada pasada por el método:

```
 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
```

Con el metodo anterior te aseguras de trabajar con la vista ya creada. Igualmente gracias a todos por responder.